# Unable to install logstash elapsed plugin in Windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logstash, elastic-stack

I have logstash 5.5 and when I run

```
./logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-elapsed
```

I get the error message

```
Error Bundler::InstallError, retrying 1/10
An error occurred while installing logstash-core (5.5.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install logstash-core -v '5.5.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

As per the logstash guide, the only requirement is jdk 8 and I have properly installed it and set my JAVA_HOME environment variable.

I've already tried so many ways including installing ruby and installing logstash-core (error again, cannot find the gem).

I'm running Windows 10. Any ideas on why this happens and how to resolve it?

Many thanks.

Comment: probably still problem, you may check this https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/6727

Comment: I downloaded the gem locally and installed it as a local gem. Not my preference though. I'm still waiting for a proper solution on logstash community as well. Many thanks for your response.